# resource injection in cdi bean

Tags: java, jms, cdi, wildfly

I'm not sure if this is supposed to work, but i'm trying to write a JMS producer with cdi with wildfly and stuck at injecting resources into a cdi managed bean:

```
public class CdiProducer {
    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    @Produces
    QueueConnectionFactory qcf;

    @Resource(name = "java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue")
    @Produces
    @Hello
    Queue helloWordQueue;
```

Running this I'm getting the following error:

JBAS016076: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named ...

What is very strange however is, when i copy&paste the resources into a enterprise bean, everything works!

```
@Stateless
public class QueueSender {
    @Resource(name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    QueueConnectionFactory qcf;

    @Resource(name="java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue")
    Queue helloWordQueue;
```

Queue is defined as:

```
  <jms-destinations>
     <jms-queue name="HelloWorldQueue">
        <entry name="/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue"/>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue"/>
     </jms-queue>
  </jms-destinations>
```

Is this supposed to work this way? Or is a bug in wildfly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using @Resource(mappedName="...")?

Comment: @Rudi Why? Resource should be able to work with the local jndi name?

Comment: In your question, you write "JBAS016076: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named ..." however you seem to have cut off the critical part.  Can you include this critical part?  Is it failing on the `Queue` or the `ConnectionFactory`?  Also, if you're using WildFly 8, you can simply inject a `JMSContext` and avoid a lot of these defaults.

Comment: @John: Both are failing, with the same error message, seems consistent with all kinds of resources.
As for JMSContext, i would love to use, but we are using wildfly for local developing, the final product needs to be deployed on a websphere 8.5, which is JEE6/JMS 1.1 only, so no JMSContext :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't have direct experience with Wildfly/JBoss, but I had the same experiences as you with Glassfish. In our case we were using `@PersistenceContext` to inject an `EntityManager`, but I believe the same rules apply.

The [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/resources.html) has a section about unifying Java EE resources and CDI. It shows how you can define a producer field (described in more detail [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e1035)) to connect such a resource to CDI in a way that means you can use `@Inject` elsewhere.

> Fields have a duality in that they can both be the target of Java EE component environment injection and be declared as a CDI producer field. Therefore, they can define a mapping from a string-based name in the component environment, to a combination of type and qualifiers used in the world of typesafe injection. We call a producer field that represents a reference to an object in the Java EE component environment a resource.
>
> ...
>
> A resource declaration really contains two pieces of information:
>   the JNDI name, EJB link, persistence unit name, or other metadata needed to obtain a reference to the resource from the component environment, and
>   the type and qualifiers that we will use to inject the reference into our beans.

Example:

```
@Produces @Resource(lookup="java:global/env/jdbc/CustomerDatasource") 
@CustomerDatabase Datasource customerDatabase;
```

Elsewhere:

```
@Inject @CustomerDatabase Datasource customerDatabase;
```

While not explicitly stated on that page, I believe the class containing this field has to be a Java EE bean, i.e. annotated with one of the EJB annotations like `@javax.ejb.Stateless` or `@javax.ejb.Singleton`.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but I ran into this same issue. When using @resource on a CDI managed bean the JNDI was always getting prepended with 'java:comp/env/'. To fix this I changed `name` to `lookup` when using `@resource` outside an enterprise bean.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```