# Resource not injecting Datasource from web.xml - Java Framework - Payara Micro - NullPointerException

Tags: java, datasource, web.xml, payara, payara-micro

My Payara REST API is working fine without DB Connection, and also Postgres localhost connection works fine through DriverManager i.e.:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "pass@123")
```

However, Datasource for postgresql in web.xml & Resource is throwing NullPointerException in below code:

```
public class AppService {
    @Resource(name="java:global/esWf")
    DataSource ds;
    
    public Response test ( 
    ...
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    ...
```

WEB-INF/web.xml: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <display-name>PG-DataSource</display-name>
    <data-source>
     <name>java:global/esWf</name>
     <class-name>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</class-name>
     <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
     <user>postgres</user>
     <password>pass@123</password>
     <property>
         <name>fish.payara.slow-query-threshold-in-seconds</name>
         <value>5</value>
     </property>
    </data-source>
</web-app>
```

I have also tried replacing url with separate elements for server, port, db name!

This is first time I am trying to connect via Datasource & Resource, and could be am missing something minor!

Links referred: - https://blog.payara.fish/setting-up-a-data-source-in-payara-micro,
https://dzone.com/articles/easy-java-ee-microservices-with-payara-micro,
Payara DB Examples etc

Error: -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.dms.DmsSrv.test(DmsSrv.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1636)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the same issue as in [resource injection in cdi bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463102/resource-injection-in-cdi-bean).

Injection using `@Resource` doesn't work in plain CDI beans and JAX-RS resources. It only works in enterprise beans.

You have 2 options:

- turn your bean into a stateless EJB - just add `@Stateless` annotation to the class:

```
@Stateless
@RequestScoped
@Path("app")
public class AppService {
    @Resource(name="java:global/esWf")
    DataSource ds;
    
    public Response test (
```

- Create a CDI producer and then inject the datasource as a CDI bean. The best practice is to use a qualifier to mark which DS you want to inject (in case there are multiple datasources in the app):

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Eswf {
}
---------------
@RequestScoped
public DsProducer {
  @Produces
  @Resource(name="java:global/esWf")
  @Eswf
  Datasource eswfDatasource;
}
------------------
@RequestScoped
@Path("app")
public class AppService {
    @Inject
    @Eswf
    DataSource ds;
    
    public Response test (
```

P.S. I think that you also need to change the JNDI name to use the `java:app/` namespace instad of `java:global/` because the DS should be available only to the deployed application. You can test whether you can retrieve the DS by JNDI name using `new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/esWf"). That should work anywhere in your application, not only in EJBs.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am going to try this.